# In python, how can I check if the uncertainties associated with a group of values are distributed normally?

Tags: python

The title is pretty self explanatory. I'm fairly new to coding and stats, and I'm trying to test if the errors on some values are Gaussian or not. What would be the best way to do this within python? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test

Comment: The title is not fairly self-explanatory. You haven't shown how a "group of values" is even represented

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179119/normality-test-of-a-distribution-in-python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use scipy.stats.normaltest: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.normaltest.html