# Problem when testing normality with distribution with a large sample size

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, normalization, normal-distribution

I'm perfoming a normal test in python using `scipy.stats.normaltest()` on a large numbers array I've got with over 100.000 rows. The data seems to be normal distributed as shown in the following image:

[image]

But when I perform the normal test, it says that my data is not normally distributed. I've tried converting it to log scale, standardizing the data, but nothing works. I saw this post [normality test of a distribution in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179119/normality-test-of-a-distribution-in-python) where an user said ***"Essentially, normality tests almost always reject the null on very large sample sizes"*** and suggested a more visual approach, with the orange line being a perfect normal distribution:

[image]

But the thing is, isn't there a more formal way for me to prove this is normally distributed?

Comment: This is a question which can be answered with certainty without any kind of test: any real data set is not normally distributed. The question for any practical application is, how non-normal is the data set? and that's a question which is not answered with a normality test.

Comment: So it actuallydepends on the interpretation of the person doing the analysis, right? On how much can you apply concepts of a normal distribution on your data.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Whether the data are "normal enough" depends on what you are trying to achieve. You know for sure already that the data are not truly normal, so the only question is whether they are normal enough. That's a very interesting question, although you should take it up on stats.stackexchange.com instead of SO.

Comment: You can check for skewness and kurtosis values too.