# Check for normal distribution

Tags: python, time-series, normal-distribution

With the informations bellow can I say that my data follow a normal distribution ?

Else is theire other way to check that?

PS: the data are values of pressure inside oil pipelines every minute from sensors.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [normality test of a distribution in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179119/normality-test-of-a-distribution-in-python)

Comment: That looks more like a [Pareto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) (or some other long-tailed) distribution, not a normal distribution.

Comment: Or more likely, a [skew normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the number of bins in your histogram plot.
You can also try visualising your data with a qq plot, looking at other statistics such as kurtosis or perform test for normality.

Looking at the sample size of your data, it seems that it should produce somewhat of a normal distribution. However looking at your histogram plot, there seems to be extreme values > 2 s.d. You might want to look into that, to determine if you want to add a dummy variable to account for it in any future analysis.